# How to exclude last child in css pseudo class selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to apply a particular style for child div from  4  to n-1 .i was able to do from 4 to n , but could not exclude the last div

here is the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/8WLXX/

```
.container div:nth-child(n+4)   {     background: red; }
```

All I want is exclude last div also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `:not(:last-child)` to the selector:

```
.container div:nth-child(n+4):not(:last-child)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
.container div:nth-child(n+4):not(:last-child) {
    background: red;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8WLXX/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by using `.container div:nth-child(n+4):last-child`

**For Instance,**

```
.container div:nth-child(n+4):last-child{
      background:none;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8WLXX/4/)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:

```css
.nth-test div:nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(n+2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nth-test">
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>foo</div>
</div>
```